# Free software to alert me on desktop upon new entry in RSS feed

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, rss

Is there any software I can use in the Gnome desktop environment on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 that alerts me of a new entry in one of my subscribed feeds, via something visual like a popup, glowing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/). It shows a different icon in the notification area on new entries.

Comment: Thanks! At first I thought I would need to actually open the window to see new updates, but it puts a small world icon on the right side of your top bar as well.

Comment: The "right side of your top bar" is the notification area.